# Pass by value trouble with java's list add method

Tags: java, arraylist, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

list2.add("foo");
System.out.println(list2); //[foo]
list1.add(list2);
System.out.println(list1); //[[foo]]
list2.set(0, "bar");
System.out.println(list2); //[bar]
System.out.println(list1); //[[bar]]
```

The code above shows 2 lists. When I add `list2` (containing `foo`) to `list1` they both now contain `foo`. But when I modify `list2` to `bar`, `list1` will change as well. I've always thought the add method only gives a copy of `list2` to `list1` and what I do to `list2` will not change for `list1`.

How can I make it that I add `list2` to `list1` but allow `list2` to be freely modified in the future so `list1` will not be affected again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java *references* are passed by value, not the object referenced.  This means that `list2.add(list1);` cannot alter the reference `list1` but it takes a reference to the same object and if you change that it is visible.

The way you should write this is

```
List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

list2.add("foo");
System.out.println(list2); //[foo]
list1.add(new ArrayList<String>(list2)); // take a copy of the list.
System.out.println(list1); //[[foo]]
list2.set(0, "bar");
System.out.println(list2); //[bar]
System.out.println(list1); //[[foo]]
```

or

```
list1.add(list2); 
list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("bar");
System.out.println(list2); //[bar]
System.out.println(list1); //[[foo]]
```

> My example above is simple but my actual problem is buried in nested loops and such.

```
List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

for(some loop) {
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    // populate list2, can be smaller than the previous list2 !!
    list1.add(list2);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why not `clone`?

Comment: Awesome thanks. Just wondering if this is the cleanest way to do it? My example above is simple but my actual problem is buried in nested loops and such.

Comment: `clone()` is not public for `List`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The OP's code use `ArrayList` variable anyway. You modified the code to use `List`

Comment: @meiryo there is a simple solution, don't re-use the same list by moving this declaration into the nest loop.

Comment: @nhahtdh It is generally not a good idea to use the collection specific methods.  It usually means you are trying to do something unusual and suspect. BTW ArrayList.clone() returns an `Object` which you have to cast with an unchecked warning which is rather ugly.

Comment: @nhahtdh..Also it is not advisable to use `clone()` method in general. Whenever you need to use it, use a `copy constructor` instead, which is being done here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice at both Rohit Jain and Peter Lawrey.

Comment: @RohitJain AFAIK `clone()` is only recommended for primitive arrays.

Answer (score 1):

How about `list1.add(list2.clone());` ?
This will create a copy of `list2` (allocate memory, clone contents etc) and put reference to it in `list1`.

Comment: While this is technically correct, it is better to add more information into the answer.

Comment: Using clone() has the disavantage that if you have a new list with less elements for some reason, the previous elements will be left as they were.

Answer (score 0):

You should clone every item and add to a new list.